# android how to work with progressdialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have an application in that i have an activity where it fetches data from server. and showed in an activity. I did that.'
but i want that progressdialog should be there if any problem with internet connection came then it should show the the problem with internet.

means i have to give time for progressbar if it crosses the 10sec then that warning alert should come to tell "problem with internet"
What i write to show the progres dialog and how to give time limit for that.
please give me the answer.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-progress-dialog-example

http://androidcore.com/android-programming-tutorials/622-simple-progress-bar-dialog-in-android-with-thread.html

http://androidcore.com/android-programming-tutorials/471-progressbar-updating-using-message-handler.html

http://androidcore.com/android-programming-tutorials/459-progressbar.html

http://androidcore.com/android-programming-tutorials/96-display-progress-bar-after-a-dialog-in-android.html

Read the tutorial related to progress bar using the given above link.
I hope it is useful to you.